# How to work with ViewModelLocator in Mvvm Light

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have just started to use and learn mvvm pattern with the help of MVVM Light toolkit. I want to use MVVM Light in my project but I dont know how to use ViewModelLocator. I am not getting what it is used for. Kindly suggest with samples or examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The locator is a repository of view models.  You use it to get access to the view models in your application.  The app.xaml defines a global instance of the locator, and individual views can bind their datacontext to properties of the locator which serve up the individual VMs. Check out my [sample app](http://cid-427749d05e37d212.office-df.live.com/self.aspx/Bits/MVVMLightMessaging.zip) to see how things are wired together.

Comment: Chris. Am interested in geting sample code. the link takes me to my windows.live then???? (am logedin but nothing happens any idea?)

Comment: Link is incorrect. Try this - https://g76esg.sn2.livefilestore.com/y1pVk7PybreyCsU4XVzEgmhtRQkUysYjhU-zbZZl0x8LWsf1EF58PWAt2smR1Tlea3905UCkKWZvCMwgwWLpRjxEA/MVVMLightMessaging.zip?download&psid=1 .